# How to execute sqoop job from oozie?

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I'm not able to execute a sample job from oozie using sqoop command to import data into hive. I've placed the hive-site.xml in hdfs path but I think it's not picking the hive-site.xml file. I'm getting class not found exception. How to fix this?

workflow.xml

```
<!-- This is a comment -->
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4" name="oozie-wf">
   <start to = "sqoop-node1" />
   <!--Step 1 -->
   <action name = "sqoop-node1" >
   <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
     <job-tracker></job-tracker>
     <name-node></name-node>
     <command> import command </command>
   </sqoop>
   <ok to="end"/>
   <error to="kill_job"/>
   </action>
   <kill name = "kill_job">
   <message>Job failed</message>
   </kill>
   <end name = "end" />
</workflow-app>
```

```
nameNode=ip jobTracker=ip queueName=default user.name=oozie oozie.use.system.libpath=true oozie.libpath=/user/hdfs/share/share/lib/sqoop oozie.wf.application.path=workflow path outputDir=/tmp/oozie.txt
```

> java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf

Comment: Post code in your question, not in the comments. Click the edit button to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your Sqoop action requires the **HCatalog library** to interact with the Hive Metastore. And Oozie does not add that library by default, you have to require it *explicitly*.

Note that there is some literature about using HCatalog from Pig, but very little from Sqoop. Anyway the trick is the same...
From [Oozie documentation](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a17.1_Action_Share_Library_Override_since_Oozie_3.3):

> Oozie share libraries are organized per action type...
>  Oozie
>   provides a mechanism to ***override*** the action share library JARs
>   ...
>  More than one share library directory name can be specified
>   for an action ... For example: When using HCatLoader and HCatStorer in
>   pig, `oozie.action.sharelib.for.pig` can be set to `pig,hcatalog` to
>   include **both** pig and hcatalog jars.

In your case, you need to override a specific `<property>` in your Sqoop action, named `oozie.action.sharelib.for.sqoop`, with value `sqoop,hcatalog` -- then Oozie will provide the required JARs at run-time.

Comment: !#/bin/bash

    table=$1

    sqoop job --exec ${table}

Comment: Sorry I wanted to post a link. Please have a look at `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43623544/sqoop-job-shell-script-execute-parallel-in-oozie`