# sqoop job shell script execute parallel in oozie

Tags: shell, hdfs, sqoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I have a shell script which executes `sqoop job`. The script is below.

```
!#/bin/bash

table=$1

sqoop job --exec ${table}
```

Now when I pass the table name in the workflow I get the sqoop job to be executed successfully.

The workflow is below.

```
<workflow-app name="Shell_script" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
<start to="shell"/>
<kill name="Kill">
    <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<action name="shell_script">
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <exec>sqoopjob.sh</exec>
        <argument>test123</argument>
        <file>/user/oozie/sqoop/lib/sqoopjob.sh#sqoopjob.sh</file>
    </shell>
    <ok to="End"/>
    <error to="Kill"/>
    </action>
    <end name="End"/>
</workflow-app>
```

The job executes successfully  for table `test123`.

Now I have 300 sqoop jobs same like above. I want to execute 10 sqoop jobs in parallel. All the table names are in a single file.

Now I want to loop to the file and execute 10 sqoop jobs for first 10 tables and so on.

How can I do this? should I prepare 10 workflows? I am literally confused.

Comment: Well, in theory, you can do all that in a shell script; no need for a scheduler such as Oozie. It would be a bit crude, and a little tricky to coordinate the parallel executions, but on the other hand Oozie was never meant to manage hundreds of micro-jobs either... and Oozie does *not* support any kind of loop.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter So, as you said we can achieve that in oozie? is this correct. If so how can we do it.

Comment: What? Quoting myself: _" you can do all that in a **shell script**"_

Comment: You do not need to prepare 10 workflow... Prepare a single workflow call it through shell script and pass your table name as argument.

Comment: List your table in file and pass it 10 table at a time through loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @`Samson Scharfrichter` mentioned you can start parallel jobs in the shell script. 
Make a function `runJob()` in shell and run it in parallel.
Use this template:

```
#!/bin/bash

runJob() {
tableName="$1"
#add other parameters here

#call sqoop here or do something else
#write command logs
#etc, etc
#return 0 on success, return 1 on fail

return 0
}

#Run parallel processes and wait for their completion

#Add loop here or add more calls
runJob $table_name &
runJob $table_name2 &
runJob $table_name3 &
#Note the ampersand in above commands says to create parallel process

#Now wait for all processes to complete
FAILED=0

for job in `jobs -p`
do
   echo "job=$job"
   wait $job || let "FAILED+=1"
done

if [ "$FAILED" != "0" ]; then
    echo "Execution FAILED!  ($FAILED)"
    #Do something here, log or send messege, etc

    exit 1
fi

#All processes are completed successfully!
#Do something here
echo "Done successfully"
```

Comment: Ideally even though it is not the correct way to do things in oozie. Your answer works in the Linux shell scripting side. Thank you for your answer