# is it possible to execute more than one hive queries parallely

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I have a script where it will read & execute one hql at a time,but i want to execute more than one hql at a time.Please let me know is there any way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `hive -e 'some command'` you can use [Bash &](http://hacktux.com/bash-ampersand/):

```
hive -e 'some command' &
hive -f someFile.hql &
etc..
```

Comment: when i execute the below command, only test.hql is executing and for test1.hql is returning as command not found.                                      
hive -f test.hql & test1.hql

Comment: in your bash script, you should have several lines: hive -f someFile.hql & hive -f someFile2.hql & etc... each hive command in a new line

Comment: ampersand should be the last character in the line. It means run in background. Also you can wait for completion of all your scripts, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43632853/2700344

Answer (score 0):

### Approach 1 (oozie):

One of the easiest and straightforward approach to run all your hql's is to use oozie. Create an oozie job and define hive actions in parallel and submit your job.

### Approach 2 (Shell):

Create multiple shell scripts, with each shell script having a `hive -e '<<query>>'` and run all the shell scripts in parallel with a cron job (or again you can use oozie to run the shell scripts).

Although approach 2 works, I'd recommend approach 1 since oozie is the way to go to run hive scripts in parallel.